# Linux login from Active Directory domain with two-way trust

Tags: linux, active-directory, sssd, ubuntu-22.04

I don't have much experience in linux tools for infrastructure and authentication with Active Directory.

I'm configuring authentication to AD on Ubuntu 22.04. The structure we use is as follows:

- we have a local AD with windows server 2019 DOMAIN1;
- an AD domain in another geographic location that is connected over VPN, I don't know which version of Windows, DOMAIN2.

There is a two-way trust between the 2 domains.
On Windows machines authentication on both domains works perfectly.

In DOMAIN1 we have access permission as an administrator. Using the `sssd-ad sssd-tools realmd adcli` packages in Ubuntu 22.04 I was able to configure DOMAIN1 on the machine and login with DOMAIN1 users.

However, it is not possible to authenticate users from DOMAIN2.

All of our users are in DOMAIN2. DOMAIN1 we only have accounts for a few  specific cases.

I checked the possibility of configuring two domains, like here: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-sssd-to-work-with-multiple-active-directory-domains-in-different-forests-centos-rhel/. However, for the command

`adcli -vvv join --host-keytab=/etc/krb5.keytab.domain2.com domain2.com -U LinuxAD@domain2.com`

The configuration requires  administrator permission on DOMAIN2. I don't have administrator access on DOMAIN2, which is managed by another team. Before bothering them, I would like to know if there is any way to configure it without needing a user with administrator permissions.

Is there a possibility to configure domains with bidirectional trust without having to perform the join procedure in DOMAIN2? Or something along those lines?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In Active Directory with two domains and a two-way trust, users from Domain2 should be able to logon to resources in Domain1, without additional AD permissions or changes, including the trust(s), unless selective authentication is enabled. Need more information than `not possible to perform authentication` though. This could be a permissions issue on the local resource (server) on Domain1. As in the server typically has the Authenticated Users security principal added to the local users group. Or explicitly grant permission to Domain2\Users to logon to the server.